# How to blacklist classes with stylelint?

Tags: css, web-frontend, stylelint, tooling

I'm integrating [basscss](https://github.com/basscss/basscss) into an app codebase and want to use [stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) to lint my existing app codebase for classes that could conflict. My idea to prevent bugs was to blacklist those classes in my app [stylelint configuration](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration/). Any idea how to do this? The [full list of stylelint rules](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/example-config/) does not show a specific rule for this but it does have a [selector-class-pattern](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern/) rule that looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

Currently I have solved this using [`selector-class-pattern`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern/) and [this blacklist regex](https://gist.github.com/ryanve/004dcaecf1fe4835345385b4d1500c78)

```
var blacklist = "^(?!(flex|flex-column|flex-wrap)$).+"

module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "selector-class-pattern": [blacklist, { severity: "warning" }]
  }
};
```

Comment: I am looking to block this pattern `xyz-[0-9]` or `abc-[0-9]`. any idea how can I do it?